# ¿Cómo modificar una lista ordenada de tal manera de que entre cada elemento no exista una diferencia menor a hmin ni mayor a hmax?

Tags: c++

> Implemente una función
>
> ```
> void homogeniza(list<int> &C, int hmin, int hmax);
> ```
>
> Que recibe una lista C de enteros ordenados en forma ascendente y la modifica de tal manera de que entre cada elemento no exista una diferencia menor a hmin ni mayor a hmax. Se deben seguir los siguientes lineamientos: Se recorre la lista desde el primer elemento. Dado un elemento a_j:
>
> - Eliminar todos los elementos siguientes hasta que el a_{j+1} sea a_{j+1}>=a_j+hmin.
> - Si a_{j+1}>a_j+hmax entonces insertar después de a_j los elementos a_j+hmax,
>     a_j+2*hmax, a_j+3*hmax,... mientras sean menores que a_{j+1}.
>
> Ejemplo:
>
> 1. recibe-> C = [0, 1, 4, 5, 10, 18], hmin=2, hmax=3
>
>    sale-> C = [0, 3, 5, 8, 10, 13, 16, 18]
> 2. recibe-> C = [1, 10], hmin=2, hmax=3
>
>    sale-> C = [1, 4, 7, 10]
> 3. recibe-> C = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], hmin=2, hmax=3
>
>    sale-> C = [1, 3, 5]

Necesito ayuda para resolver este problema. No se como manejar los iteradores para llegar a la solución.

Mi codigo:

```
void homogeniza(list<int>& C, int hmin, int hmax) {
  // COMPLETAR...
  auto it = C.begin();
  while(it != C.end()) {
    while(*(++it) < ((*it)+hmin)) {
      it = C.erase(it++);
      --it;
    }
    if(*(++it) > ((*it)+hmax)) {
      int i=1;
      while(((*it)+i*hmax) < *(++it)) {
        it = C.insert(++it, ((*it)+i*hmax));
        ++i;
      }
    }
    //++it;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que es más facil resolver el problema usando dos iteradores en vez de solo uno:

```
void homogeniza(std::list<int>& C, int hmin, int hmax) {
  for( auto it = C.begin(); it != C.end(); ++it)
  {
    auto it2 = std::next(it,1);
    if( it2 != C.end() )
    {
      for( ; it2 != C.end() && ( *it + hmin > *it2 ); )
        it2 = C.erase(it2);

      if( it2 != C.end() )
      {
        if( *it + hmax < *it2 )
          C.insert(it2,*it+hmax);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Usar solo un iterador complica el código ya que tienes que estar jugando todo el rato con desplazamientos sobre el mismo iterador... que oye, también es posible hacerlo con uno solo:

```
void homogeniza(std::list<int>& C, int hmin, int hmax) {
  for( auto it = C.begin(); it != C.end(); ++it)
  {
    int valActual = *it;
    std::advance(it,1);
    if( it != C.end() )
    {
      for( ; it != C.end() && ( valActual + hmin > *it ); )
        it = C.erase(it);

      if( it != C.end() )
      {
        if( valActual + hmax < *it)
          it = C.insert(it,valActual+hmax);
      }
    }
    std::advance(it,-1);
  }
}
```